# Mail not sending from Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, email, servlets

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlet-web] in context with path [/xxx] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
```

this is throwing internal server error in browser and no mail is sent with javax api.

While simple java file with the code :

```
EmailSender emailSender = new EmailSender();
emailSender.setDefaultProperties();
emailSender.sendEmail(EmailSender.USERNAME, EmailSender.PASSWORD, EmailSender.FROM, "vkeerocks@gmail.com", "Test Mail", "<b> Hi there!!! </b>");
```

But the same if I put in the controller then throwing error.

this is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"register"}, method = {RequestMethod.PUT}, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public
@ResponseBody User registerUser(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletResponse response)
{


    if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
    {
        logger.debug("Serving request for registering user: " + user.toString());
    }

    boolean success;
    try
    {

        logger.warn("Registering user : " + user.toString());

        this.userService.insertUser(this.convertUserToUserDto(user));

        EmailSender emailSender = new EmailSender();
        emailSender.setDefaultProperties();
        emailSender.sendEmail(EmailSender.USERNAME, EmailSender.PASSWORD, EmailSender.FROM, "vkeerocks@gmail.com", "Test Mail", "<b> Hi there!!! </b>");

        success = true;

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("While serving the request for registering user :", e);
        success = false;
    }

    return user;

}
```

Comment: Have you actually read the stacktrace? `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException` is pretty clear. Add the java mail api to your project.

Comment: thanks Deinum i have done it, i put the javax.mail.jar into tomcat lib directory and it worked but its a spring angular mvc project having maven integrated so what is the need of manually putting the api...any suggestions are invited....

Comment: Then it wasn't a dependency in your pom. The fact that you use maven doesn't mean your dependencies are automagically discovered. Make sure that you have added the javax.mail dependency as a compile time and not provided dependency in your pom.

Comment: tnks Deinum but the main problem is that i am using INtelliJ Idea ie IDE which have its own library so some suggestion how to change the configuration so that it automatically loads the dependencies from its library

Comment: Intellij has nothing to do with it. It is maven, the ide is just a tool. The command-line/build-server that is the truth not your IDE. As stated you are using maven add the library to your pom (and fix your Intellij to use the maven dependencies and not its own libraries!!!).